# Why does operator precedence works other way with variable assignment in Javascript

Tags: javascript, operator-precedence

I have a code like this.

```
let y = 2;
y *= 3+4;
```

The above line is a short hand of `y = y*3+4`. So as per the precedence level, `*` should take a precedence. So i am expecting a calculation like this, `(2*3)+4` so that should return `10`. But why does it executes this way `2*(3+4)` and returned `14`. Can somebody explain in detail?

Comment: "The above line is a short hand of y = y*3+4" - no it's not.

Comment: `y*=3+4` === `y = y*(3+4)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's helpful to see how the JS parser interprets that statement: https://esprima.org/demo/parse.html?code=y%20*%3D%203%2B4

Binary expressions are evaluated before assignment expressions.

The `+` is a binary expression that has 3 and 4 as operands.

The `*=` is an assignment expression that has, on the left hand side, `y`, and on the right hand side, the result of the binary expression (3 + 4, or 7).